# Fresh T3 app, Auth doesn't work on Vercel

Tags: next.js, vercel, next-auth, t3

I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jqVm5_G1ZEE) on how to create a T3 app.

To summarize, this is what I did:

- `npm create t3-app@latest`, use TypeScript, include all 4 features
- in this case I left the DB as the default SQLite (but I tried PlanetScale too just to do exactly as the video shows)
- I tried both the default Discord, and also Google OAuth 2.0
- Pushed to Git
- I had Vercel read from the Git, set up all the env variables

On local it works perfectly, I can sign in with both Discord and Google.

But **on Vercel** I kept getting

> Try signing in with a different account.

(with Discord after "Authorize"-ing, with Google Auth as soon as I click the "Sign in with Google" button).

I'm a bit of a noob here. What am I missing?

Comment: What are you using for auth , next-auth , clerk , supabase or other maybe ? also did you try to refresh deployment after setting env on vercel .